# How do I find Adjustments & Other Charges?

Tags: api, ups

I am using the UPS API for shipping and tracking orders.

Sometimes, UPS adds an additional amount to my invoice titled 'Adjustments & Other Charges'

Is there a way to access this data (after shipping) via the API? so my client doesnt have to type them in manually when he physically recieves the invoice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If anyone stumbles across this, then here's the anwer from UPS:

> Thank you for your inquiry. 'Adjustments & Other Charges' are provided
>   by UPS Billing. There is no way to access them via the API. More
>   information about billing adjustments can be found at the link
>   provided below:
>
> https://www.ups.com/content/us/en/resources/sri/bil_faq8.html?srch_pos=5&srch_phr=adjustments
>
> Please contact us if you need any additional assistance.